# How to use interface for KVM from ISP?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, bridge, arp, aliases

i have main IP:

`1.2.3.4` with mask `255.255.255.0` and gateway `1.2.3.254`

It is ok. Also, ISP gave me network `/28`. List of ip:
from `1.1.1.1` and until `1.1.1.15`

I can use these interfaces via aliases, like `eth0:1, eth0:2, etc ...`

How can i use these `15` interfaces for KVM ? Also, my configuration file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 1.2.3.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 1.2.3.254
        up ip link set eth0 txqueuelen 10000

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 1.1.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.240

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 1.1.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.240

...
...
...
```

How can i use these interfaces for my KVM ? What ways to use aliases in KVM ? Bridge ? Proxy_arp ? I did bridge for vlans, but how i know it does not work for alises. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to create a bridge with the interface eth0 and attach virtual machines interfaces to this bridge, and not to use aliases. See how to do it: [Configure public IP addresses in KVM VMs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245628/configure-public-ip-addresses-in-kvm-vms).
You config will look like this if you create vmbr0 (and assign main ip to it).

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 1.2.3.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 1.2.3.254
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

Comment: but i need to use these interfaces. i not need to use main ip. i need to use diapason of ISP

Comment: You do not need to use main IP, you can assign one (few) IP addresses to your VMs.

Comment: This is correct. You must use a bridge, and assign the IP addresses to each VM, not to the hypervisor.